# Angular router populate parent outlet

Tags: angular

First off, here's a stackbliz link to what I'm trying to do:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yiaszs

If you click the `To Bill` button, the route changes but nothing fills in.

If you go into `src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html` and uncomment out the one line, then click the `To Bill` button, it'll work.

Basically I'm trying to get the button to populate a parent `router-outlet`. Is this possible?

I've tried all sorts of combinations in the `modal: ['bill']` line... `['../bill']`... etc...

P.S. Please ignore the routing structure as it's inherited code and matches the actual application routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change what the route navigation is relative to in the click handler to `relativeTo: this.route.parent` - you want to change the parent view.

```
public onClick() {
    this.router.navigate([{
      outlets: {
        modal: ['bill']
      }
    }],
      {
        relativeTo: this.route.parent
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Errrmergerrrrdddd. Thank you!!